# Invalid key length issue when trying to do encryption in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do encryption and decryption in nodejs.

**encrypt.js**

```
  module.exports=function(crypto) {
        algorithm = 'aes-256-gcm',
        password = 'd6F3Efeq';
        iv = '60iP0h6vJoEa';
        this.testFunc=function(text) {
            var cipher=crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm,password,iv);
            var crypted=cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
            crypted +=cipher.final('hex');
            var tag=cipher.getAuthTag();
            return {
                content:encrypted,
                tag:tag
            }
        }
    }
```

when I call the testFunc() with parameter it shows following error.

```
Error: Invalid key length
    at new Cipheriv (internal/crypto/cipher.js:139:16)
    at Object.createCipheriv (crypto.js:98:10)
    at module.exports.testFunc (/var/www/html/nodejs/encrypt.js:26:21)
    at /var/www/html/nodejs/routes.js:17:19
```

I am followed [this link](http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/) to create encryption and decryption in nodejs.

Comment: I am not familiar with 'aes-256-gcm', May be issue in your password length try with this password which given in "this link" '3zTvzr3p67VC61jmV54rIYu1545x4TlY'

Answer (score 2):

> Error: Invalid key length

You're getting this error because your key `d6F3Efeq` is just 8 characters in length. `aes-256-gcm` requires the key to be 32 characters in length.

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, 'd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeqd6F3Efeq', iv);
```